# Show that every non-constant polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$ is separable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, separable-extension

Suppose that $K$ is a field of characteristic $p\gt 0$, where $p$ is a prime, and suppose that the Frobenius homomorphism $\phi: K\to K$, where $\phi(\alpha)={\alpha}^p$, $\forall \alpha\in K$ is surjective. Show that every non-constant polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$ is separable.

I have difficulties to find the connection between the given and the conclusion.

All I can see is that,

$1.$ Since $\phi$ is a field homomorphism, it is injective automatically. So $\phi$ is actually a bijection.

$2.$ If $\operatorname{char}(K)=p$, then all polynomials in the form of $f(x)=x^p-k\in K[x]$ is irreducible.

Then I have no idea what to do. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: 2 is false, and it being false all the time given 1, is exactly why the conclusion holds.

Comment: Didn't you forget  the condtion ‘an *irreducible* polynomial in $K[X]$ is separable?

Comment: @jgon How come? I'm pretty sure 2 is true.

Comment: @TangTang Take a look at the answer below to see why 2 is false.

Comment: @Bernard Why is that? An irreducible polynomial may have repeated roots in its splitting field as well I think?

Comment: If the Frobenius homomorphism is surjective, the field  is perfect.

Comment: @jgon $a$ may be from $E\setminus K$, where $E$ is its splitting field. In this case, $x^p-k=(x-a)^p$ is irreducible in $K[x]$.

Comment: @Bernard That is exactly what I need to prove.

Comment: @TangTang But $k\in K$, and you know the map $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^p$ is surjective from $K$ to $K$, so there is $a\in K$ with $a^p=k$. Thus, while that's true in general that $a$ might be in $E\setminus K$, in this case $E=K$, so that's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $k = a^p$ for some $a$, so $x^p - k = (x-a)^p$.